# Django / Python unorderable types Story() < Story() with sorting function

Tags: python, django, sorting, typeerror

I am currently learning Django from scratch using the Django Unchained TutsPlus course, I've got to a point where a top_stories function is being created to sort each story, each story starts with 1 point.

I tried many things, for example putting abs around the return from the score function works, however this will cause a negative score to become positive, the main problem arises when each story has the same score, because then it sorts via the story I think?

Python version - 3.3.3

Django version - 1.6.1

**This is the error displayed**

```
ERROR - unorderable types: Story() < Story()
```

**views.py - line 16 is causing the problem, the line with sorted on**

```
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.utils.timezone import utc
from stories.models import Story

def score(story, gravity=1.8, timebase=120):
    points = (story.points - 1)**0.8
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    age = int((now - story.created_at).total_seconds())/60 # minutes since story was posted
    return points/(age+timebase)**gravity

def top_stories(top=180, consider=1000):
    latest_stories = Story.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:consider]
    ranked_stories = sorted([(score(story), story) for story in latest_stories], reverse=True)
    return [story for score, story in ranked_stories][:top]


def index(request):
    stories = top_stories(top=10)
    response = '''
    <html>
    <head>
           <title>Tuts+ News</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <ol>
       %s
       </ol>
    </body>
    </html>
    ''' % '\n'.join(['<li>%s</li>' % story.title for story in stories])
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

I would be very grateful for any help with this, been trying to fix it for a while now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `key` function to give stores a score:

```
ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=score, reverse=True)
return ranked_stories[:top]
```

This removes the need for a decorate-sort-undecorate pattern you were using, and happily also avoids comparing individual `Story` instances without ordering support.

You probably should use `heapq` here instead and avoid sorting the *whole* list:

```
import heapq

return heapq.nlargest(top, latest_stories, key=score)
```

A `heapq.nlargest()` call is computationally less complex as a full sort; the smaller `top` gets compared to `consider` the greater the difference, performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response, works perfectly, been searching around for ages for a fix

Comment: To add to the answer: the reason sorting fails is because the way Python sorts tuples is by comparing the first element and, if those are equivalent, comparing the second element. I guess in this case you must have had a tie and so it went to the 2nd element in order to try to break the tie - at which point it found that Story objects aren't orderable.

Comment: Claudiu yeah I thought this was why it was happening, weird though because it works on the guys computer who is doing the tutorial

Comment: @theo3335796: Either because on his machine he's not using Python 3, he augmented the `Story` class to add ordering support (`__eq__`, `__lt__`, etc.) or he doesn't have any scores that are equal for the test set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh yeah because he scraped his stories from another website so they will all have different scores, I guess I found a bug maybe haha. Also I have implemented heapq, thanks for the tip! Any reason its faster than sorted()?

Comment: @theo3335796: When sorting, you apply a O(NlogN) algorithm, but a heap only needs O(NlogM) to find the M top values with N-sized input. When M < N, that makes the heap faster.

Comment: Yep, worked for me.  The Tuts+ tutorial is definitely a version or two behind - which makes it a tough one but you learn more by debugging anyhow ---- right? ;-)